# Can a f-2 visa holder request for status termination to re-marry a US citizen?

Tags: us-citizens, marriage, california, divorce, f2-visa

If someone came to the US with F-2 visa while she and her husband(F-1 visa holder) are not US citizens nor permanent residences, and their marriage happened in their home country, can she(F-2 visa holder) request to terminate her F-2 status and just after that marry with a US citizen?

Is it needed to get a legal divorce either within the US or their home country embassy before she can marry a US citizen even if she has terminated her F-2 status?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot be married to two different people in the US, [it's a crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamy_in_North_America#United_States) (it doesn't matter where you've gotten married). So you'll have to divorce your current spouse (the F-1 holder), and as a consequence lose your eligibility to the F-2 status. If you intend to stay in the US during the divorce and start a relationship with a US citizen - you should probably get both a family law and an immigration law professionals to advise you.

Comment: @GoodMan The last sentence of this answer — the one that begins "You should probably get..." is the most prudent advice that can be given to your three questions.